# jmd. etwas zukommen lassen (gewähren) - Konjugation

Tags: meaning, tense, conjugation

I play with the verbal form `jmd. etw. zukommen lassen` in the sense of `gewähren` and I am not sure about conjugation in the passive form:

```
Er wird den Vorrang zukommen gelassen.
Er wurde den Vorrang zukommen gelassen.
Er ist den Vorrang zukommen gelassen worden.
```

I have a doubt, `Er wird den Vorrang zugekommen gelassen`?

Is in the previous sentences the sense also right, he is/was/has been given the priority ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diese sind alle falsch:

```
Er wird den Vorrang zukommen gelassen.
Er wurde den Vorrang zukommen gelassen.
Er ist den Vorrang zukommen gelassen worden.
```

Richtig wäre:

```
Ihm wird der Vorrang zukommen gelassen.
Ihm wurde der Vorrang zukommen gelassen.
Ihm ist der Vorrang zukommen gelassen worden.
```

Üblicher ist wohl:

```
Ihm wird der Vorrang gelassen.
Ihm wurde der Vorrang gelassen.
Ihm ist der Vorrang gelassen worden.
```